# The probability that a point is close to a hyperplane that is orthogonal to the principal diagonal must be very big.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, inequality, contest-math

Let $\mu^n$ be the uniform probability measure on the $n$-dimensional cube $[-1,1]^n$. Let $H \in\mathbb{ R}^n$ be the hyperplane orthogonal to the principal diagonal, i.e., $H = (1,\cdots ,1)^\perp$. For any $r > 0$, we further define
$$A_{H,r}:=\{x\in[-1,1]^n,\text{dist}(x,H)\le r\},$$
where $\text{dist}(x,H)$ represents the distance from the point $x$ to the hyperplane $H$. Show that for any constant $\epsilon > 0$, the following estimate hold for all sufficiently large $n$
$$\mu^n(A_{H,n^\epsilon})\ge1-e^{-n^{\epsilon/2}}$$
$$$$
It is not hard to prove the inequality $\mu^n(A_{H,n^\epsilon})\ge1-n^{-2\epsilon}$. However the stronger inequality form this problem is too strong with $e$ as exponential. I think to prove the stronger inequality we may need further make use of the "hyperplane orthogonal to the principal diagonal" hypothesis. Are there any ways of deriving this stronger inequality?

Comment: The distance from $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ to $H$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left| \sum_i x_i \right|$, so you can view the problem as a statement about the deviation of a sum of uniform random variables on $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: $$\operatorname{dist}(x,H)=|x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n|/{\sqrt n}.$$ So this is a question about the sum of $n$ i.i.d. of uniform random variables, and in particular, the probability of the sum being within $n^{\epsilon+1/2}$ of the mean. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Presumably, you have a reason to believe this is true? Like, it is part of an exercise? If so, what are some of the results covered in the preceding chapter? Context gives a lot of clues for how people can help you. Help people help you.

Comment: This is a problem from a math competition, and there’s no clue or hint….To me it’s hard to believe this is true since the right bound is too strong

Comment: @Ho-Oh If it is from a contest, then you should edit the question to say so and specify its source.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/32403#32403.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from classical concentration inequalities (used for large deviation estimates), in particular the Chernoff bound. However, I think it is more instructive to illustrate the technique used to prove the Chernoff bound by deriving the desired inequality from scratch, as follows.

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent random variables uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$. Then
$$
\mathbb P(|X_1+\cdots+X_n|>t)\leq 2\mathbb P(X_1+\cdots+X_n>t).
$$
By Markov's inequality,
$$
\mathbb P(e^{aX_1+\cdots+aX_n}>e^{at})\leq \mathbb E[e^{aX_1}]^n e^{-at}=\sinh(a)^na^{-n}e^{-at}.
$$
From the Taylor expansion of $\sinh(a)$ it follows that for all $|a|$ less than some absolute constant, the inequality $\sinh(a)\leq a+a^3$ holds, thus for all such $a$
$$
\mathbb P(X_1+\cdots+X_n>t)\leq (1+a^2)^ne^{-at}\leq e^{na^2-at}.
$$
The quadratic in the exponent is minimized when $a=t/2n$. Choose $n$ sufficiently large ensures that $a$ is small enough for the previous inequality to apply, thus for all such $n$
$$
\mathbb P(X_1+\cdots+X_n>t)\leq e^{-t^2/4n}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\mu^n(A_{H,n^{\epsilon}})=\mathbb P\left(|X_1+\cdots+X_n|\leq n^{\epsilon+1/2}\right)\geq 1-2e^{-n^{2\epsilon}/4}.
$$
Since $\epsilon>0$, we have that $2\epsilon>\epsilon/2$ and thus the inequality is stronger than the one desired in the question.

Comment: We need to estimate $\mathbb P(X_1+\cdots+X_n>t)$, but instead of directly estimating this we applied Chebshev to $\mathbb P(e^{aX_1+\cdots+aX_n}>e^{at})$. Although they’re equivalent, may I ask what is the intuition of analyzing $\mathbb P(e^{aX_1+\cdots+aX_n}>e^{at})$ instead of $\mathbb P(X_1+\cdots+X_n>t)$?

Comment: Here's the intuition. We want to exploit the fact that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent in order to get a good bound (because such a strong inequality becomes false when they aren't independent). The right way to exploit independence is by working with *products* rather than *sums* of the random variables (so that the expectation factorizes - using independence; sums don't detect independence). To turn things from sums into products, we exponentiate. By the way, this is the same reason why the characteristic function of a random variable is often more useful than the CDF.